# Edit files with template

Tags: python, replace

I have a lot of files which consist of some string. I have to remove it from all of files. How can I do this faster? Any ideas, prefer python-script, for example.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -i "s/YOUR_STRING//g" *

/* or */
for file in `grep YOUR_STRING -l *`; do sed -i "s/YOUR_STRING//g" $file; done
```

first method will blindly remove the `YOUR_STRING` for all files

second method probably will break if too many files matched

**updated** : is not a python solution, ping me if you dislike and will delete it

Comment: What it the line is big and has a few newlines?

Comment: like `sed -i "s/some very long string\n\n\n\n\nline2\nline3//g"`

Answer (score 1):

`sed -ie "s/SEARCH/REPLACEMENT/g" *`

http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

Comment: @ajreal: sorry, next time I will refresh page before posting :-D